# Limitting results in association

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to limit the results in a lateral join, so that it only returns the N most recent matches.

This is my query, but the limit inside the join does not seem to work, as it returns all visitors

```
select am.id, am.title, ame.event, array_agg(row_to_json(visitors))
from auto_messages am
left join apps a on am.app_id = a.id
left join app_users au on a.id = au.app_id
left join auto_message_events ame on ame.auto_message_id = am.id
left join lateral (
    select 
        id,
        name,
        avatar,
        ame.inserted_at
    from visitors v
    where v.id = ame.visitor_id
    order by ame.inserted_at desc
    limit 1
) as visitors on visitors.id = ame.visitor_id
where am.id = '100'
group by am.id, ame.event
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure the problem is with `ame`.  That is where the rows are generated.  The `join` to `visitors` is only picking up additional information.

So, this might solve your problem:

```
select am.id, am.title, visitors.event, array_agg(row_to_json(visitors))
from auto_messages am left join
     apps a
     on am.app_id = a.id left join
     app_users au
     on a.id = au.app_id left join lateral
     (select v.id, v.name, v.avatar,
             ame.event, ame.inserted_at, ame.auto_message_id
      from auto_message_events ame join
           visitors v
           on v.id = ame.visitor_id
      order by ame.inserted_at desc
      limit 1
     ) visitors
     on visitors.auto_message_id = am.id
where am.id = '100'
group by am.id, visitors.event;
```

You also might want to change your `select` clause, if you only want a subset of columns.